# Farther plane is rendered in front of closer one

Tags: java, opengl-es, libgdx

I have a libgdx aplication, where i created a maze that consists of cubes.
When I render the bottom **blue** and the top **red** face, bottom one is rendered in front of the top face. Both faces have the same normal vector.

Could I have switched far and near clipping plane ?

Here is how I set up the camera:

```
public PerspectiveCamera updateCamera() {
       if (camera == null) {
          float aspectRatio = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
          camera = new PerspectiveCamera(67f, aspectRatio, 1);
          this.setActive(true);
      }
      return camera;
}
```

[image]
[image: Bottom is clearly below top]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just forgot to add depth testing.

Added to create() method:

```
Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
Gdx.gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LESS);
```

Added to render() method:

```
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```